# The file 79477bd-8433-4c41-ad1f-864996d663ae couldn't be opened because there is no such file

Tags: ios, objective-c

I sometimes got my program crash with this error.

I do not know what 79477bd-8433-4c41-ad1f-864996d663ae is

```
self.searchBrochures = [brochuresIDs convertToFaultForClassWithThisIDs:[Image class]];

//PO(self.searchBrochures);
[self.myTableView reloadData]; //It crashes here
```

I set breakpoint at:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

**and**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

However, only numberOfRowsInSection is called. cellForRowAtIndexPath is not even called. And yet things crashed.

I wonder what's wrong and how can I debug this?

When crash it goes directly to main even though I have break on all exception.

Here is a screenshot

[image]

Comment: what is the data going to be stored in self.searchBrochures?  Check always array type of objects are placing or missing any case?

Comment: PO self.searchBrochures  at numberOfRowsInSection() method for debugging...

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem is. I tried running the application on simulator. The simulator crash at the same spot but with a better message.

The simulator said that some object is not key value compliant for some key.

Turns out I removed one property and there is still a view that has a referencing outlet to it. Fixing it fix the problem.

This bug has a very misleading error message.